# C# Create and initialize (with non-default value) a readonly flaot array?

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point

I need to create a `readonly` float array and initialize all of its elements with the value `1.0f`. I am trying to use the following syntax but it is showing an error, "`The modifier readonly is not valid for this item`".

```
int nRows = SomeData.Rows;
int nCols = SomeData.Cols;
readonly float[] myFloatArray = Enumerable.Repeat(1.0f, nRows * nCols).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is `myFloatArray` a local variable or a field?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Local variable.

Comment: You can't use modifiers on local variables. Do you really need to make the array read-only in local scope?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: Thanks. I have made it field :)

Comment: Are you aware that readonly means you cannot re-assign the reference, not that you cannot edit the values?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content of the array to be readonly, which wouldn't be the case even if you could use the `readonly` modifier, the closest thing to a readonly array you'll find is a [ReadOnlyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly).

```
int nRows = SomeData.Rows;
int nCols = SomeData.Cols;
var myFloatArray = Array.AsReadOnly(Enumerable.Repeat(1.0f, nRows * nCols).ToArray());
// var is System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<float>
```